# JAX-WS Client - Setting Connection Timeout and Request Timeout as a Command Line Option

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am trying to set the Connection Timeout and Request Timeout properties on my JAX-WS Client, able to do this programmatically using :

```
Map<String, Object> reqContext = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();
reqContext.put(BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, conTimeout);
reqContext.put(BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, reqTimeout);
```

However, is there a way to set these properties as Command Line options (using the -D flag)?

Tried -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout=900000 and -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout=900000 but these don't seem to work.

Comment: What is the application server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout` and `sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout` system properties instead